# The method setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) is undefined for the type Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, layoutparams

I want to set my Bitmap's layout size before instantiating it so it can be instantiated (if not, its layout height & width are = 0).

I am using this simple code in my custom View :

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
    mBitmap.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}
```

On the line `mBitmap.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);` I get the error

```
The method setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) is undefined for the type Bitmap
```

Found nothing about it neither on SO or even on Google (using the " " because I didn't get anything near to be useful without them).

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Layoutparams are used to set for views not for bitmap you can set it to Imageview or other view which you using

Comment: I did set them for my custom view (DrawView) in my MainActivity, and that made it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setlayoutParams` is a method of View class (and its descendents) object.

You should set the Bitmap to a View (explicitly it's an ImageView) by calling `setImageBitmap`. You can call `setLayoutParams` to the View.

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
    // of course you should instantiate mImageView anywhere beforehand
    mImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    // set mBitmap to mImageView
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap); 
}
```

Comment: pretty much what I did thanks to @Pavan 's explanation, but thank you for the sample code, might help someone else (and I might even use it to make my project cleaner)